# Code not breaking after promise has been executed

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, lambda, promise

I currently have an issue in Node.js whereby I make a call to a mysql database using the promise-mysql and bluebird packages. I followed the tutorials on the webpage and it seems to work. I keep ending up with a timeout error as once the database has been queried the process doesn't break (if that's the right term) and I either have to terminate the process using ctrl + c or when testing on Alexa when the skill replies with there was a problem. Is there a way to end the promise and db connection once I have retrieved the value of my query? Below is an example of the code.

**index.js**

```js
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
const querydb = require('./sqlQuery.js');
const insertdb = require('./sqlInsert.js');


var testSQL = 'SELECT weight, height from users where pin=1100';

var valuesPromise = querydb.getItem(testSQL);
valuesPromise.then((result)=>{
    rows = result.height;
    row2 = result.weight;
    console.log(rows);
    console.log (row2);
    return true; 

}).catch(function(error){
        console.log (error);
});
```

**databaseConnection.js**

```js
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "hostURL",
    database: "dbName",
    user: "dbUser",
    password: "dbPassword",
    connectionLimit: 1
});

function getSqlConnection() {
  return pool.getConnection().disposer(function(connection) {
    pool.releaseConnection(connection);
  });
}

module.exports = getSqlConnection;
```

**sqlQuery.js**

```js
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var getSqlConnection = require('./databaseConnection');

function getItem(sql){
    return Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function(connection) {
        return connection.query(sql).then(function(rows) {
          return rows[0];
        }).catch(function(error) {
          return (error);
        });
    })
};



module.exports.getItem = getItem;
```

Comment: Maybe don't use the pool,..   Or if you do use the pool make sure you call `end`,..

Comment: Make sure all local members are declared as such with var/let/const. `pool`, `rows`, `rows2` are undeclared.

Comment: Returning a caught error sends it down the promise chain's sucess path, which is (typically) incorrect. As the `valuesPromise` chain expects to be able to catch an error, don't catch it in `getItem()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in node process you can just exit from it with `process.exitCode = 1` and then `process.exit()` or `process.exit(1)`.

[Here is the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit).

[That however is not the best practice](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2014/02/04/maintainable-node-js-javascript-avoid-process-exit/). The easiest way would be to just throw an error:

`throw "Exit!"` or some error you would like to catch and re-throw to exit (in the scenario where you have a catch statement)